# A module cannot have multiple default exports in ReactNative

Tags: react-native

I am new to ReactNative. I am following a tutorial. I have copied the code from the tutorial and getting the error "A module cannot have multiple default exports". Code is

```
// Parent 
export default class ScreenOne extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <View>
                <Heading message={'Custom Heading for Screen One'}/>
            </View>
           )
         }
}

// Child component
export default class Heading extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{this.props.message}</Text>
            </View>
               )
             }
}
Heading.propTypes = {
    message: PropTypes.string
}
Heading.defaultProps = {
    message: 'Heading One'
}
```

I know i am missing something really simple, but any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's exactly what the error shows. There are 2 `export default` there. You can have only one per component. Also, each component must be in different files.

Comment: I am pretty sure, the author of the code meant these snippets to be in different files. i.e. something like parent.js and child.js, just to be sure could you please share the tutorial link as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put child component in other file and import it in parent component file.

Child component in `heading.js` file

```
export default class Heading extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{this.props.message}</Text>
            </View>
               )
             }
}
```

Parent component

```
import Heading from "./heading.js";

export default class ScreenOne extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <View>
                <Heading message={'Custom Heading for Screen One'}/>
            </View>
           )
         }
}
```

Golden rule: Never make more than one component in file.

Comment: Thanks. I am also getting the error on "<Text>{this.props.message}</Text>" line. Error is "Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'". Can you kindly tell how to resolve it.

Comment: I guess you left "message" prop in parent file you need to pass it to child component line this `<ChildCopm messageToPassToChild={this.props.message} />` and get messageToPassToChild from props in your child component

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. After invalidating caches and restarting WebStorm it worked again.